# Klockwork warning: Null pointer dereference of where null is returned from a method

Tags: java, warnings, klocwork

While doing bug analysis using klocwork, I am getting warning `Null pointer dereference of 'nextLineDn' where null is returned from a method`.

Apparently other static analysis tool `findbug` also gives same warning.

But clearly i am checking for null/empty before using it.

```
      int noOfLines = device.getLines().size();     
        if( lineNo != 0 && noOfLines > lineNo ) // if next line exists      
        {   
            nextLineDn = device.getDn(lineNo+1);    
            if(!Util.isNullOrEmpty(nextLineDn)) 
            {       
                return (nextLineDn.contains("@")) ? nextLineDn.split("@")[0] : nextLineDn;  
            }       
        }
```

`class Util` :

```
public static boolean isNullOrEmpty(String str) {
    return (str == null || str.isEmpty());
}
```

can someone give me some idea on this? 
i am getting so many warning with same conditions.Dont know what else can be done to remove the warning.

Comment: Post the stack trace

Comment: this is static analysis tool. `getDn` returns null in case nothing found.

Comment: @BalwinderSingh: Please check [TagInfo](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/klocwork/info)

Answer (score 1):

Since Klocwork Insight is a static source code analysis tool, it might not be able to further decipher that you have a method named isNullOrEmpty() in Util class, wherein you are actually doing a null check. So, it is showing warnings in your IDE.

Static analysis tool tries to find potential flaws in advance. So, here Klocwork would tell : *`device.getDn()` might return null, be careful with using `nextLineDn`*.

But, if you put code like `(nextLineDn!=null)`, I guess it would not flag a warning there. (Try and let us know)

Comment: yes its correct. But error is coming only with Strings. If i use some other object its not giving warning, for example some class objects.

Comment: Can you please check device.getDn() method and see, if it shows explicitly that it can return null? For example, initializing string to null,`String returnString = null;` Then for some reason, later getDn() returns null, as returnString is not being assigned a non-null value in that scenario. Can you compare the same with non-String object, the methods returning them, whether there is a possibility of returning null or not? Because, static analysis tools generally would identify potentialities of null-references in this manner: _If a method can possibly return null, then caller can deference_

Comment: Yes it returns null if ,function argument`(dnNumber)` is null. Thats the only case.